# std::thread::detach causes crash after original caller is destroyed

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, detach, stdthread

```
struct Test {
    bool active{true};

    void threadedUpdate() {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1));
        if(!active) // crashes here after Test instance is destroyed
            return; 
    }

    Test() { 
        std::thread([this]{ while(true) threadedUpdate(); }).detach();
    }

    ~Test() { 
        // somehow stop the detached thread?
    } 
};
```

When an instance of `Test` is initialized, it spawns and detaches an `std::thread` which runs in background. When the same instance is destroyed, the previously mentioned thread tries to access the `active` member, which was destroyed along with the instance, causing a crash (and an *AddressSanitizer* backtrace).

**Is there a way to *stop* the detached thread on `~Test()`?**

The design is bad. **How should a thread running in background until the caller is destroyed be spawned/handled correctly?**

Comment: As a general rule, you shouldn't detach a thread unless that thread controls the lifespan of any resources it is using. This thread is using `Test` but does not control its lifespan, therefore it should not be detached.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Make the thread a member of the class, and instead of detaching it in the constructor, join it in the destructor. To stop the thread from looping, you can have a boolean inside the class that signals whether the thread should continue running or not (`std::atomic<bool> update`).

The thread could be executing this: `[this] { while (update) threadUpdate(); }`.

In the destructor of your class, do `update = false`, and call `thread.join()`

Comment: @VittorioRomeo - otherwise you'd need a mutex to protect it. According to the standard, non-`atomic` types are never safe to access concurrently without explicit synchronization if at least one of those accesses is a write.

Comment: Another question: would using a member std::future<void> and launching the function with std::async be cleaner instead? I suppose it wouldn't require an explicit join.

Comment: It could reduce the potential for human error (e.g forgetting to join the thread in the destructor), so it might be worth it.

Answer (score 8):

You can't stop detached threads. That's the point of [`.detach()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/detach) - you don't have *any* way to refer to the detached thread anymore, at least as far as the C++ standard specifies. If you want to keep a handle to the thread, store the `std::thread` and call `.join()` in the destructor.

Comment: Is it really necessary to call `.join()` in the destructor if instead of `while(true)` I use `while(active)` and set `active = false;` in the destructor? Shouldn't the thread be stopped then?

Comment: Another question: would using a member `std::future<void>` and launching the function with `std::async` be cleaner instead? I suppose it wouldn't require an explicit join.

Comment: Probably it would work, but in general the cleanest solution is to release *all* resources in the destructor, even those that would be released asynchronously. This presumably requires calling join.